# Passing a variable through multiple levels of partials with EJS

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I'm trying to figure out how pass a variable through multiple levels of partials with EJS.

At the top-level, I have a page of my form. I'm trying to define a % completion to pass back to the progress bar, which is hosted in one of my lower-level partials.

```
<% layout('./form/formPartial.ejs', { progress: 10 }) %>

        <div class="container pt-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>Running habits and goals</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <p>Get started by telling Fittir about your running habits and goals.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container mt-auto">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <p> Time to complete: 5minutes</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

^ gets the layout from a partial lower-down, which includes the footer and header. I want to pass the variable progress, defined in ^, into the formHeader partial (see below)

```
<% layout('layouts/form_boilerplate') %>

    <form class="form" action="" method="POST">
        <%- include('../partials/formHeader', { progress: progress }) %>

            <div class="form-body d-flex flex-column">
                

                <%- body %>
            

                <div class="container mt-auto">
                    <%- include('../partials/formFooter') %>
                </div>
            </div>
                
    </form>
```

which then populates the progress bar, and progress completion.

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="/logos/logo-primary.svg" class="logo-primary"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="progress mt-2 px-0">
                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<%= progress %>" aria-valuemin="0"
                            aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <%= progress %>%"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col px-1">
                        <p><%=progress %>% completed</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</header>
```

It is not working though. I get a reference error (see below).

```
ReferenceError: /Users/anthonyg/vscode/fittir/views/form/formPartial.ejs:4
    2| 
    3|     <form class="form" action="" method="POST">
 >> 4|         <%- include('../partials/formHeader', { progress: progress}) %>
    5| 
    6|             <div class="form-body d-flex flex-column">
    7|                 

progress is not defined
```

Any ideas?

When I passed it through one-level, e.g defined it at the mid-level partial, it wouldn't through a reference error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply that `layout` function has only 1 argument which is the layout file path `layout(view)`. Try to refactor your code with `include` or `partial` to be able to pass params.

[See documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHHfp.png)